# Can't enter the Dictionary<> code in C#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

It seems that no matter where I enter `Dictionary<>` in my code or class, it just wont be accepted and it produces an error. I get `Invalid token` for brackets and parenthesis and I get `System.Collections.Generic <Dictionary<String, MediaClass> is a type but used like a variable`

I've done various searches, but no result has helped. I just need to know where in my code do I declare `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can see how you are actually declaring the Dictionary?

Comment: Add a whole code sample please.

Comment: @StephenWilson I don't need to provide any sample code because I just needed to know how to declare Dictionary<>, and a simple Google search didn't give the result I wanted.

Comment: @MythrilMagician - You really do need to play nice with the SO community. So please help make your questions a quality resource for the SO community by posting your code when asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you posed the question it seems like you are missing the type parameters. (The things in the angle <> brackets)

1. The first is the key type.
2. The second is the value type.

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). First make sure you include the namespace.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

You can declare a dictionary like this.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

or without var

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

We can add to our dictionary like this.

```
dictionary.Add("4", 4);
dictionary.Add("230", 230);
```

Some common operations on dictionaries.

```
dictionary.Add("42", 42);      
dictionary.Count();            // 3
dictionary.ContainsKey("3");   // false
dictionary.ContainsValue(230); // true
dictionary.Remove("230");
dictionary.Count();            // 2
dictionary.Clear();
dictionary.Count();            // 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But one more question: How do you do it so that each new listbox item adds to the dictionary? So far I have done this

         `public void Dictionary()
       
       {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, MediaClass>();
        }`